# Rendering/Flickering/Glitch issue in Chrome using CSS 'backdrop-filter:blur'

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I do face a rendering problem using backdrop-filter: blur(12px); in Chrome 76 on MacOS Mojave. Whenever I start to hover with my mouse over the opened tabs in Chrome, the div using the backdrop-filter starts flickering and the div is subdivided into smaller rectangles having different colors and are split by horizontal lines with shadows.

I don't know if it's a rendering problem, a glitch, some overflow problem or just a bug in Chrome.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jd3987nf/) is the fiddle.

I already tried variations of:

- transform: translateZ(0);
- backface-visibility: hidden;
- overflow: hidden;
- margin: 0
- will-change:top;
- position: static;

Nothing seemed to work.

Minimal Example:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="articleViewOverlay" class="articleViewOverlay">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
.articleViewOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: dashed;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.4); 
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Here's another example of recreation of that strange behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/jxkfh9b8/embedded/result The whole browser starts flashing (Chrome 79, Mac OS X El Capitan) when I move the mouse over browser tabs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, my guess is that you're encountering [this bug](https://crbug.com/986206). If so, feel free to star that bug (top-left corner) to get updates. There aren't any workarounds at this point, but it's work in progress.

Comment: That's exactly the problem I've been facing. Thank you! :) I'll guess I just have to wait for a fix. Until then, I'll just do a simple blur with the elements below the modal that is displayed.

Comment: Just for posterity, this bug was fixed in Chrome 79 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, adding this to the element being blurred fixes it:

```
 -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

because if forces gpu rendering

Answer (score -1):

The bug was [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=986206#c59) in Chrome build 79.0.3945.1 (Oct 16th, 2019)

Comment: I still experience those big flashes in Chrome 80.0.3987.149. Just recreated it opening the JSFiddle I posted in the OP comments: moving the mouse over tabs, adress bar, bookmarks makes huges flashes... Update: Also with the OP fiddle...

Comment: @neoDev Interesting... I am on 80.0.3987.132 and the issue in my own projects (and the fiddle) are fixed now

Comment: I am on Chrome 80.0.3987.149 and the bug is still there

Comment: Still not fixed...

Comment: On chrome 97 still an issue.

Comment: On Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 still not fixed

Comment: Make a comment on the bug tracker, nobody has said anything since 2020 there. They won't see this.